# keeping Eclipse-generated makefiles in the version control - any issues to expect?

Tags: c++, eclipse, version-control, makefile

we work under Linux/Eclipse/C++ using Eclipse's "native" C++ projects (.cproject). the system comprises from several C++ projects all kept under svn version control, using integrated subclipse plugin.

we want to have a script that would checkout, compile and package the system, without us needing to drive this process manually from eclipse, as we do now.

I see that there are generated makefile and support files (sources.mk, subdir.mk etc.), scattered around, which are not under version control (probably the subclipse plugin is "clever" enough to exclude them). I guess I can put them under svn and use in the script we need.

however, this feels shaky. have anybody tried it? Are there any issues to expect? Are there recommended ways to achieve what we need?

N.B. I don't believe that an idea of adopting another build system will be accepted nicely, unless it's SUPER-smooth. We are a small company of 4 developers running full-steam ahead, and any additional overhead or learning curve will not appreciated :)

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have used the generated makefiles (subdir.mk, etc etc) to create a static makefile manually, which i then started to version control and switched Eclipse to not generate the makefiles anymore but use the version controlled one when building. It was a quite smooth transition and now i update my master makefile manually when adding source to the project. It is also great to be able to use the very same makefile for code analysis tools that need the project built a bit differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is a big problem (I had exactly the same; in addition: maintaining a build-workspace in svn is a real pain!)

Problems I see:

- You will get into problems as soon as somebody adds or changes project settings files but doesn't trigger a new build for all possible platforms! (makefiles aren't updated).
- There is no overall make file so you can not easily use the build order of your projects that Eclipse had calculated

BTW: I wrote an Eclipse plugin that builds up a workspace from a given (textual) list of projects and then triggers the build. That's possible but also not an easy task.
Unfortunately I can't post the plugin somewhere because I wrote it for my former employer...

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend putting things that are generated in an external tool into version control. My favorite phrase for this tactic is **"version the recipe, not the cake"**. Instead, you should use a third party tool like your script to manipulate Eclipse appropriately to generate these files from your sources, and then compile them. This avoids the risk of having one of these automatically generated files be out of sync with your root sources.

I'm not sure what your threshold for "super-smooth" is, but you might want to take a look at **[Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)**, which has a plugin for Eclipse projects to do just this.

Comment: thanks! a quick look at what is Maven page shows "a tool that can now be used for building and managing any Java-based project". Is it good for C++ projects?

Comment: Maven itself is built with Java, but it can manage and build pretty much any project format under the sun that's in widespread use.